# How to fix the 66671 AudioQueueInternalNotifyRunning error when playing a sound?

Tags: swift, audio, avfoundation

I'm writing an application in Swift, and I believe the code is all valid, as there are no compiler errors. When I try to play an audio file that I know exists, I get the error listed below.

No audio plays.

I have tried writing the code different ways, including instantiating the AVAudioPlayer with the contentsOf argument.

```swift
import UIKit
import CoreML
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let soundURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "beep", withExtension: "mp3")!
        var soundPlayer : AVAudioPlayer!
        do {
            soundPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL)
        }
        catch {
            print("Err")
        }
        soundPlayer.play()


    }

}
```

Here is the error:

```
    2019-10-18 22:35:29.609690-040 Test[. . .] [plugin] 
AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID . . . > . . 

   2019-10-18 22:35:30.527132-0400 ML Test[19542:1516755] [aqsrv] AQServer.cpp:68:APIResult: Exception caught in AudioQueueInternalNotifyRunning - error -66671
```

Comment: Move the line `var soundPlayer : AVAudioPlayer!` to _before_ `func viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I had the same issue when tried to reuse the same player multiple times. But in my case, the problem was related to setting currentTime without stoping this player. So the solution was to stop the player before setting new currentTime.

Comment: @Timur Bernikovich, for me I use slider to change the audio track's current playtime and after set `slider.isContinuous = false` I silence this error. Because, I don't care the values change during the dragging of slider, instead I only care where the user release the drag.